# Print parts of a panda dataframe to another (new) dataframe iteractively

Tags: python, pandas

The following dataframe  was created from a binning average with `pd.cut`

```
                           A           B     binned
              A 
          (-0.1, 0.1]   0.100000    4.200000    1
          (0.1, 0.3]    0.165000    0.000000    6
          (0.3, 0.5]    0.416000    1.000000    5
          (0.5, 0.7]    0.666667    5.333333    3
          (0.7, 0.9]    0.850000    1.000000    2
          (0.9, 1.1]    1.000000    0.000000    4
```

I have just learned that the best way to iterate over the dataframe is by using `itertuples()`, by doing so:

```
            for row in df.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
               if row.binned <=4:
                print(row.A,row.B)
```

Instead of printing, what's the most appropriate way to save the results of row.A and row.B to a .csv file? By first creating a `pd` and writing to a csv? If yes, how?

Comment: _I have just learned that the best way to iterate over the dataframe is by using `itertuples()`_ Which is almost always inferior to vectorized methods. _Instead of printing, what's the most appropriate way to save the results of row.A and row.B to a .csv file, by first creating a pd and writing to a csv._ Select the rows you want, combine them using `pandas.concat()`, and write the resulting DataFrame to CSV ? I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: try for loop with groupby `for group,bin in df.groupby('binned')  : group.to_csv(f'{bin}.csv')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- first filter the dataframe

```
df = df[df['binned']<=4]['A','B']
```

2- write it to csv

```
df.to_csv('name.csv')
```